# CodeIgniter - change nav link based on session data

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have an home controller who control the homepage (that is a simple landing page with no user interaction or dynamic data):

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

  private $data;
  protected $pagedata;

    function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == true) {
      $this->data['nav'] = 'auth/template/homelogin_nav';
    }
    $this->pagedata['title'] = 'La Giumenta Bardata Cosplay & Props'; 
  }

    /**
     * Index Page.
     *
     **/
    public function index()
    {
    $this->load->view('template/header', $this->pagedata);

    $this->load->view("template/nav", $this->data);

    $this->load->view('section_header');
    $this->load->view('section_about');
    $this->load->view('section_services');
    $this->load->view('section_portfolio');
    $this->load->view('section_social');
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
}
```

So basicly, if user is log in I load a certain view that correspond to a nav, if not it's loaded the normal menu.
Now, the two navs are different just for one link (one nav's view has a link to the login page and the other one has a link to the user dashboard).

I also try this:

```
$this->load->view($this->data);
```

but of course is illegal and it doesn't work. 
The problem starts because I have to check for the session in the costruct and not inside the `function index()` or I can't check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you check for session inside of view? 
Make one navigation and if user is logged in show dashboard, if not show login button in navigation.

Navigation view:

```
<ul>
    <li> <?php echo anchor('home','Home'); ?> <li>   

<?php    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')== true){

        echo "<li>".anchor('dashboard','dashboard')."</li>";
        echo "<li>".anchor('logout','logout')."</li>";
}else
        echo "<li>".anchor('login','login')."</li>"; ?>
</ul>
```